# Python loop not iterating through the list

Tags: python, loops, exchangelib

I have this code, where I'm trying to loop through a mailbox with specified email-adresses in a list, but instead I'm getting the output of all email-adresses. When I print the counts, I get like 10 different email adresses, but not the ones I've limited to in the lists. How do I make it print only the ones from my list "emails"

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
from collections import defaultdict

emails = ['test1@random.com','test2@random.com']

for email in emails:
    credentials = Credentials('hidden@hidden.com', 'hiddenpass')
    account = Account('hidden@hidden.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
        counts[item.sender.email_address] += 1
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate on the `emails` list. If you want to filter emails that don't appear in the `emails` list, you can do something like:

```py
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    if item.sender.email_address in emails:
        counts[item.sender.email_address] += 1
```

I'm not familiar with this library, but maybe you have the option to grab only the relevant results with something similar to:

```py
account.inbox.all().filter(sender=email).order_by('-datetime_received')
```

As noted by [@erikcederstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828284/python-loop-not-iterating-through-the-list/63828439#comment112869552_63828439), you can get better performance if you fetch only senders:

```py
account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received').only('sender')
```

Comment: If you want this to go a *lot* faster, consider limiting the number of fields to just the one you need: `account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received').only('sender')`

Comment: @ErikCederstrand so what you mean by that is `account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received').only('exampleemail@email.com') `

Comment: No. I meant what I wrote.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand Wow tak Erik det var meget hurtigere! Thanks Erik it was very fast now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the following (if I understand you correctly). We increase counts variable as before, but print only ones that are in `emails`:

```py
credentials = Credentials('hidden@hidden.com', 'hiddenpass')
account = Account('hidden@hidden.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
counts = defaultdict(int)
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    counts[item.sender.email_address] += 1
    if item.sender.email_address in emails:
        print(item.sender.email_address)
        print(counts[item.sender.email_address])
```